# for each co-ordinates in the object, I want to get the staddress and city

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-leaflet, reverse-geocoding

i want to get the staddress and city for each array of objects, but i get same staddres and city for all the objects. For the actual project i get the co-ordinates by clicking on the map and using mapEvents to get the latlng. The co-ordinates gets stored in the workouts array.  Here is the simplified [sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hill-ykffj?file=/src/App.js)

```
export const WorkoutsData = [
  {
  id: 1,
  coords: {latitude: 56.27360151291927, 
  longitude:-82.84886256490017},
  },
  
  {
  id: 2,
  coords: {latitude: 49.27360151291927, 
  longitude: -75.84886256490017},
  },

  {
  id: 3,
  coords: {latitude: 39.27360151291927, 
  longitude: -79.84886256490017},
  }
];



import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { WorkoutsData } from "./WorkoutLocation";

const App = () => {
  const [workouts, setWorkouts] = useState(WorkoutsData);
  const [cityName, setCityName] = useState([]);

  const id = (Date.now() + "").slice(-10);

  useEffect(() => {
    workouts.map((workout) => {
      fetch(
        `https://geocode.xyz/${workout.coords.latitude},${workout.coords.longitude}?geoit=json`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          setCityName([`${result.staddress}, ${result.city}`]);
        });
    });
  }, [workouts]);

  return (
    <>
      <div key={id}>
        {workouts.map((workout) => {
          return <h2 key={workout.id}>{`${cityName}`}</h2>;
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried many other methods. I was able to get the specific location name for the workout objects, but the first `cityName` didn't render and the fist `cityName` got passed onto the second workout object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things I spotted with your code preventing it from working correctly. The first is that as you depend on the previous state value, you need to use the functional version of `setState` when you update the `cityName` state. Instead of:

```
setCityName([...cityName, `${result.staddress}, ${result.city}`]);
```

use:

```
setCityName((prev) => [...prev, `${result.staddress}, ${result.city}`]);
```

Another problem is that when you iterate over the workout data and perform the HTTP request to retrieve the city data, you're adding the results to the `cityName` array in the order the HTTP requests are received (the HTTP request for the 2nd workout might come back before the HTTP request for the 1st one, and it will get added at position 0 rather than position 1). To fix this, you can change the type of `cityName` to be an array of an objects:

```
[
  {
    workoutId: // The ID of the workout
    cityName: // The city name (returned from the geocode API) for the workout
  }
]
```

then `setCityName` becomes:

```
setCityName((prev) => [
        ...prev,
        {
          workoutId: workout.id,
          cityName: `${result.staddress}, ${result.city}`
        }
      ]);
```

The HTML to output the city name can be changed to retrieve the city name for the specific workout being rendered:

```
<div key={id}>
    {workouts.map((workout) => {
      return <h2 key={workout.id}>{`${getCityName(workout.id)`}</h2>;
    })}
</div>
```

The following lookup function will be required to return the city name that corresponds to the workout ID:

```
const getCityName = (workoutId) => {
  return cityName.find((city) => city.workoutId === workoutId)?.cityName;
};
```

I've produced a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cdn-u9yt1?file=/src/App.js:810-927) by forking your CodeSandbox to show it working. Please note that as I don't have an API key for geocode.xyz, I changed the API to use a free UK postcode lookup service (and changed the latLngs in the data accordingly). The principle is still the same though.